# invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, string

I have skipped the above part 
It is a normal c++ program using classes which prints name,age and standard

Code is as follows:

```
string to_string()
{
    return age,last_name,first_name,standard; //PROBLEM IS HERE
}
};

int main() {
    int age, standard;
    string first_name, last_name;

    cin >> age >> first_name >> last_name >> standard;

    Student st;
    st.set_age(age);
    st.set_standard(standard);
    st.set_first_name(first_name);
    st.set_last_name(last_name);


    cout << st.get_age() << "\n";
    cout << st.get_last_name() << ", " << st.get_first_name() << "\n";
    cout << st.get_standard() << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << st.to_string();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with that `return`?

Comment: I want all the strings(name,age,standard) to come in a single line

Comment: So you just assumed that you could concatenate strings with the comma operator? You should look up these kinds of things when you don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string to_string()
{
    return age,last_name,first_name,standard; //PROBLEM IS HERE
}
```

I assume you want to concatenate all the member data into one string and return that, but the comma operator just evaluates its first expression, throws away the value, then returns the value of the second expression.

You could make a `std::string` then repeatedly append to it. I think `std::stringstream` is a bit cleaner for things like this though:

```
string to_string()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << age << ' ' << last_name << ' ' << first_name << ' ' << standard;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: Then an error comes in these statements:

Student st;
    st.set_age(age);
    st.set_standard(standard);
    st.set_first_name(first_name);
    st.set_last_name(last_name);

undefined reference to Student::set_blah

Comment: @A.Bora did you define those functions? Did you link with the object file produced? Those errors are in code you have not shown here.

Comment: but arent those inbuilt functions of #include<sstream> ?

Comment: @A.Bora The issue is that the linker can't find definitions of your `Student::set_x` functions. That's unrelated to `std::stringstream`.

Comment: I have defined the functions void set_age(int age);

Comment: That's a declaration, not a definition. They need to be defined and the object file containing their definition must be linked into the executable.

Comment: can you explain it briefly?

Comment: @A.Bora please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix).